# I don't know what to do with the probability draw

Tags: php, syntax, decrement

I am currently giving a score of one or more people and choosing to draw more than one person based on the score. However, there is still a runtime error and is not being resolved. Please let me know how to this problem solve.

this is my code:

```
$selectChildrens = array();
for($i=0;$i<$recuTotal;$i++){
    $random = rand(0,sizeof($childSelectArray)-1);

    $selectChild = $childSelectArray[$random];
    $sameCheck = 0;

    if(sizeof($selectChildrens) == 0){
        array_push($selectChildrens,$selectChild);
        while(($key = array_search($selectChild,$childSelectArray)) != NULL){
             unset($childSelectArray[$key]);
        }
        $recuTotal—;
        $i=0;
    }else{
        array_push($selectChildrens,$selectChild);
        while(($key2 = array_search($selectChild,$childSelectArray)) != NULL){
            unset($childSelectArray[$key2]);
        }
        $recuTotal—;
        $i=0;
    }        
}
```

Comment: for statement is broken.

Comment: Also, this code is incredibly difficult to read. Not sure if it broke when you pasted it or not, but please consider reviewing the [PSR Coding standards](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/), and revising to help us be able to read it to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that your attempt to decrement `$recuTotal` is not using correct syntax.

Use this line instead:  `$recuTotal--`

You are using a long dash, but need two hyphens.

As for your `array_search()` lines, I always use: `!==false` though I'm not sure it matters.

Lastly, you can use `!sizeof($selectChildrens)` as a shorter if statement.

Though I'll admit I didn't fully comb your code to see what it is doing, this is a DRYer code block that will perform the same way:

```
$selectChildrens = array();
for($i=0;$i<$recuTotal;$i++){
    $random = rand(0,sizeof($childSelectArray)-1);

    $selectChild = $childSelectArray[$random];
    $sameCheck = 0;

    array_push($selectChildrens,$selectChild);
    while(($key=array_search($selectChild,$childSelectArray))!==false){
         unset($childSelectArray[$key]);
    }
    $recuTotal--;
    $i=0;
}
```